# A strange TikZ numerical anomaly with ln function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

Despite Ti*k*Z manual's making clear that PGF's mathematical libraries should not be expected to be extremely precise, there is a discontinuity when plotting the `ln` function which I find *abnormally* large (the discontinuity, which occurs about the argument value 0.125, is of roughly 0.03, which is quite visible on plots—even plots which are not made specifically to show the bug!). Even stranger, the bug disappears when the density of plotting values becomes high enough! See the following MWE and its result:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=500cm, y=50cm, thick]
\foreach \x in {0.120, 0.122, 0.124, 0.126, 0.128, 0.130}
 \draw (\x, -2.13) -- +(0, -4pt) node[below]{\x};
\foreach \y in {-2.12, -2.10, -2.08, -2.06, -2.04, -2.02}
 \draw (0.119, \y) -- +(-4pt, 0) node[left]{\y};
\draw[green] plot[domain=0.12:0.13, samples=95] (\x, {ln(\x)});
\draw[red] plot[domain=0.12:0.13, samples=94] (\x, {ln(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result showing the TikZ numeric bug with plotting ln function]

Has anyone any explanations for what happens…?

Comment: Hello
Don't use smooth!

Comment: @rpapa `smooth` option removed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know from where that comes, but, with a **recent** (works in 3.1.8b, not in 3.1.5b) Ti*k*Z/PGF you can use the `fpu` version for `ln`:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=500cm, y=50cm, thick, /pgf/fpu/install only={ln}]
\foreach \x in {0.120, 0.122, 0.124, 0.126, 0.128, 0.130}
 \draw (\x, -2.13) -- +(0, -4pt) node[below]{\x};
\foreach \y in {-2.12, -2.10, -2.08, -2.06, -2.04, -2.02}
 \draw (0.119, \y) -- +(-4pt, 0) node[left]{\y};
\draw[green] plot[ domain=0.12:0.13, samples=95] (\x, {ln(\x)});
\draw[red] plot[ domain=0.12:0.13, samples=94] (\x, {ln(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :-) I am actually even more eager to know the explanation than to get a workaround, but this is quite useful nonetheless! ;-D

Comment: Yes, I am curious too. Let's see if some of the true Ti*K*Z gurus know...

Comment: It's pretty common to experience floating point issues. Hence the `fpu` library.

Comment: @SebGlav Agreed, but here the error is huge (much more than what you would expect for a basic function like `ln`, for a quite “moderate” argument) ; and moreover, I do not understand why it disappears when you take a denser plotting grid…